# Update a variable without refreshing page

Tags: php, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tylers inclass 3</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <style>

            #game{

                position: relative;
                width: auto;
                display: block;
                top:150px;
                left:390px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;


            }

            #bg{
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 310px;
                left:230px;



            }
            #input
            {
                position: relative;
                top: 670px;
                left: 450px;

                z-index: 1;

            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="input">
            <form method="post">
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Name: </td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="text"id="name"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Bet: </td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="text"id="bet"/></td>
                        <td align="right">Credit: </td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="credit" value="100" readonly="true"id="credit"/></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>

        </form>
        </div>

        <div id="bg"> 
            <img src= "img/machine.png" width="1200" height="580" alt="machine"/>
        </div>

        <div id="h">

        </div>
        <div id="h1">

        </div>
        <div id="game">
            <?php

            function display() {
                //creating the array of pictures that will also be referenaced in the code as item
                $items = array(
                    '<a href="?item=cherry">  <img src= "img/cherries.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="cherry"/></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=cherry">  <img src= "img/cherries.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="cherry"/></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=lemon">  <img src="img/lemon.png" width="150" height="150" alt="lemon"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=bar">  <img src="img/bar.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="bar"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=bar">  <img src="img/bar.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="bar"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=bar">  <img src="img/bar.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="bar"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=star">  <img src="img/star.png" width="150" height="150" alt="star"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=star">  <img src="img/star.png" width="150" height="150" alt="star"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=star">  <img src="img/star.png" width="150" height="150" alt="star"></a>',
                    '<a href="?item=star">  <img src="img/star.png" width="150" height="150" alt="star"></a>'
                );






                $num1 = $items[rand(0, 12)];
                $num2 = $items[rand(0, 12)];
                $num3 = $items[rand(0, 12)];
                echo $num1;
                echo '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';
                echo $num2;
                echo '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';

                echo $num3;
                echo '<br><br><br><br>';
                echo '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';


                $credits = 100;
                $bet;

                //  if($items):
                //  endif;
                //echo $num2 = $items[$random_Num];
                // echo $num3 = $items[$random_Num];
                //setting a link to parent page to go back and play the full game again
                echo '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href="./" id="goback"><img src="img/button.png" width="100" height="100" alt="star" onclick=""></a>';
                echo $_GET['name'];



                //game logic test cases for rock beating scissors paper beating rock and scissors beating paper
            }


            display();
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hey Guys! I have a question. So I want to be able to take in a players name and a bet and keep track of their bids. HOWEVER the way I refresh or "update" my slot machine is a link back to the parent page.  In other words i just refresh the page on click.  How do I change these pictures on click of the button img without reloading the page. Any help is valued! Thank you

Comment: Have you heard of Ajax before !?

Comment: @Fred -ii- I havent learned ajax :/

Comment: Oh, you're gonna love it. It's one of the best things since sliced bread.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Is there any way to do it in php ?

Comment: Php is run server side before the page is sent. Therefore the only way to change whats displayed is to refresh or use javascript which runs client side (you would use Ajax along with javascript to achieve what you want).

Comment: `cabellicar123` has pretty well summed it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may send the user data by ajax.
For example, in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("form").submit(function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          $.post("sumbitName.php",{
                "name":$("#name").val(),
                "bet":$("#bet").val()
          },function(result){
               // Update...
          });
     });
 });
```